# Defining and calling a method in irb

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm struggling with understanding understanding OOP.
I am trying to use IRB to play around with Ruby and deepen my understanding.

In IRB

```
foo = Object.new
```

Creates a new object
However if I try and give irb a definition and call it on that object it doesn't work. (does the def have to happen in a .rb file and loaded into Ruby?)

```
def bar "hello" end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the method in the class you want it to apply to.

```
class NewObject
  def foo
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

these methods are called like:

```
x = NewObject.new
x.foo
```

You can create methods that are not specific to a class just by defining them:

```
 def bar
   puts "bar!"
 end
```

and just call them as:

```
bar
```

Comment: Ok Thank you! so the fact that i did not return made all the difference! silly me. Thank you!

Comment: See my edit. It explains a bit more about method in classes versus just general methods. If this solved your problem please choose "accept".

Answer (score 0):

Use `pry`

```
gem install pry
```

its better than `irb`

everything in ruby is an object

dot notation on an object means that this is a method of that object

this is why you need to wrap it inside a class / module

I suggest read here for more info:
https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables