# Issues with Quicksort in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having a lot of issues writing a Quicksort algorithm in Ruby. I'm coming from C++/ Java, so my code could be completely wrong:

```
def quicksort(*list)

   if list.empty?
        return list 
   end 

   $pivot = list.sample

   list.delete_at(list.index($pivot))

   current_element = list[0]

   $smaller = Array.new
   $larger = Array.new


   list.each do |x|
      if (list[x] <= $pivot)
         $smaller << list[x] 
      else 
         $larger << list[x]
      end 
   end 

   $sorted = Array.new

   $sorted << self.quicksort(*$smaller)
   $sorted << pivot
   $sorted << self.quicksort(*$larger)

   $sorted.flatten!

   return *$sorted 
end 

myArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
sorted = Array.new(quicksort(myArray))

myArray.each do |x|
print x 
end 

print "\n"
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2CoN.png)

Can you not set an array equal to a function that returns an array, like you could in C++ or Java?

Comment: Please add the error as text, not as an image

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you even read the error message? Where do you get the impression that the error message has anything at all to do with "setting an array equal to a function that returns an array"? I think the error message is quite clear: you defined `quicksort` as a `private` method, but you are not calling it as a `private` method. You need to call it as a `private` method, i.e. without an explicit receiver.

Comment: A couple thoughts: `$foo` in ruby is a global variable. It doesn't look like any of the variables in your function need to be global. In fact, they're probably causing you trouble because `$sorted` is being overwritten each time the function is recursively called. When you use the splat operator in `def quicksort(*list)` you are passing each element of `list` as an individual argument, rather than passing the whole list. I don't think this is what you want. Similarly, just return `$sorted` not `*$sorted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your code you [must have a class to define methods in IRB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29361555/1826279). In addition I fixed the bug with missing dollar before pivot.

```
class SortingAlgorithms
  def self.quicksort(*list)

    if list.empty?
      return list
    end

    $pivot = list.sample

    list.delete_at(list.index($pivot))

    current_element = list[0]

    $smaller = Array.new
    $larger = Array.new


    list.each do |x|
      if (list[x] <= $pivot)
        $smaller << list[x]
      else
        $larger << list[x]
      end
    end

    $sorted = Array.new

    $sorted << self.quicksort(*$smaller)
    $sorted << $pivot
    $sorted << self.quicksort(*$larger)

    $sorted.flatten!

    return *$sorted
  end
end


myArray = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
sorted = Array.new(SortingAlgorithms.quicksort(myArray))

myArray.each do |x|
  print x
end

print "\n"
```

But, beautiful ruby way provided in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371681/quick-sort-in-ruby-language).